# Microsoft Query in Excel - Specifying dynamic path for database

Tags: excel, sharepoint, microsoft-query

I'm using the Microsoft Query connection in Excel to fetch information from an Access Database on SharePoint. Everything works fine for now on my computer after I use OneDrive to sync the Sharepoint on my computer. Since the Connection String uses specific text for the 'DBQ' part, the path for the Access Database contains my username

Connection String -
**DBQ = C:\Users\%myUsername%\SharePoint...\%Access Database%.accdb**

I would like to change the above string to ensure that the query runs on any computer.

Ideally,

Connection String -
**DBQ = C:\Users\%CurrentUsername%\SharePoint...\%Access Database%.accdb**

Is there a syntax that I can use for **CurrentUsername**?

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found a solution.
The connection string recognizes the default folder path for the system, which is, in most cases, the Documents folder under the current user. I used the **'..'** syntax to refer to the parent folder which is **C:\Users\%CurrentUsername%** followed by the rest of the folder path.

**DBQ = ..\SharePoint\%Access Database%.accdb**

The other (failed) options were, to use different providers like Microsoft ACE OLEDB 12.0 and trying to provide a Network path for the SharePoint folder (it errors with "xyz.accdb is not a valid file name")